# Delete post from front end of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Here's the code I have:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$url = get_bloginfo('url');
  if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)){
    echo '<a href="';
    echo wp_nonce_url("$url/wp-admin/post.php?post=$postid&action=delete", 'delete-post_' . $post->ID);
    echo '">Delete your listing</a>';
  }
?>
```

I'm trying to delete the post outside the wordpress loop.
When I click the link, I get:

"Your attempt to delete this post: “post-name” has failed.

Please try again."

Does anyone know why that would be?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the reference, it looks like [current_user_can()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) only takes one argument.

Perhaps the root cause here is a permissions issue for the user. You should be checking if a user has the **delete_posts** capability as seen below. Note that **delete_posts** checks if the user can delete their own posts. To check if the user can delete the posts of other users, you can use **delete_other_posts** instead.

```
  if (current_user_can('delete_posts')){
    echo '<a href="';
    echo wp_nonce_url("$url/wp-admin/post.php?post=$postid&action=delete", 'delete-post_' . $post->ID);
    echo '">Delete your listing</a>';
  }
```

(Assuming you are using WP version 2.1 or later)